# SQL IDs With Multiple Transactions in 1 Day

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm having trouble even knowing what to search for, so any suggestions are appreciated.

I have a table with the following structure in SQL Server:

```
AccountID  UpdatedDate
123        11/1/2017 08:00:00:000
123        11/1/2017 20:00:00:000
123        11/2/2017 08:00:00:000

456        11/1/2017 08:00:00:000
456        11/1/2017 14:00:00:000
456        11/1/2017 20:00:00:000

789        11/1/2017 08:00:00:000
789        11/2/2017 08:00:00:000
```

I want my results set to only display the records where the transaction is the same date but different times of the day, such as:

```
    AccountID  UpdatedDate
123        11/1/2017 08:00:00:000
123        11/1/2017 20:00:00:000

456        11/1/2017 08:00:00:000
456        11/1/2017 14:00:00:000
456        11/1/2017 20:00:00:000
```

I'm not having much luck.  Any help for a struggling novice would be fantastic, thank you!!

Comment: Hi, I appreciate everyone's input. I should probably make a clarification. This is just an example data set. I have thousands of rows of data and want to pull out the ones that meet this criteria. I'm not sure a temp table inserting my examples would work in this instance. Please advise.

Comment: You should be able to implement this to meet your specific needs. If you have 2 columns, you can just replace AccountID and UpdatedDate in our solutions to get the desired results. Instead of selecting from @testTable, you would select whatever columns you need from whatever table the columns are stored in.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the most elegant solution, but it will get the results you need.

```
DECLARE @testTable TABLE (AccountID INT, UpdatedDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @testTable
VALUES ('123', '11/1/2017 08:00:00:000'), 
       ('123', '11/1/2017 20:00:00:000'), 
       ('123', '11/2/2017 08:00:00:000'), 
       ('456', '11/1/2017 08:00:00:000'), 
       ('456', '11/1/2017 14:00:00:000'), 
       ('456', '11/1/2017 20:00:00:000'), 
       ('789', '11/1/2017 08:00:00:000'), 
       ('789', '11/2/2017 08:00:00:000');

WITH accounts
AS (
    SELECT rowid = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY AccountID, cast(UpdatedDate AS DATE) ORDER BY UpdatedDate
            ), AccountID, UpdatedDate, [day] = cast(UpdatedDate AS DATE), [time] = cast(UpdatedDate AS TIME(0))
    FROM @testTable
    )
SELECT DISTINCT ch.AccountID, ch.UpdatedDate
FROM (
    SELECT accounts.day, accounts.AccountID
    FROM accounts
    WHERE rowid > 1
    ) c
INNER JOIN accounts ch ON ch.day = c.day
    AND c.AccountID = ch.AccountID
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the sample data, Rooben. no ned for the 2 CTE's though:

```
DECLARE @testTable TABLE (AccountID INT, UpdatedDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @testTable
VALUES ('123', '11/1/2017 08:00:00:000'), 
       ('123', '11/1/2017 20:00:00:000'), 
       ('123', '11/2/2017 08:00:00:000'), 
       ('456', '11/1/2017 08:00:00:000'), 
       ('456', '11/1/2017 14:00:00:000'), 
       ('456', '11/1/2017 20:00:00:000'), 
       ('789', '11/1/2017 08:00:00:000'), 
       ('789', '11/2/2017 08:00:00:000');

WITH Counts AS (
    SELECT *,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID, CONVERT(date,UpdatedDate)) AS C
    FROM @testTable)
SELECT AccountID,
       UpdatedDate
FROM Counts
WHERE C > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    AccountId INT,
    UpdateDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
(123,'11/1/2017 08:00:00:000'),
(123,'11/1/2017 20:00:00:000'),
(123,'11/2/2017 08:00:00:000'),
(456,'11/1/2017 08:00:00:000'),
(456,'11/1/2017 14:00:00:000'),
(456,'11/1/2017 20:00:00:000'),
(789,'11/1/2017 08:00:00:000'),
(789,'11/2/2017 08:00:00:000')

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        SeqNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AccountId,CAST(UpdateDate AS DATE) ORDER BY UpdateDate),
        *
        FROM @T
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE C1     
    WHERE EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1 FROM CTE WHERE AccountId = C1.AccountId AND SeqNo > 1 AND CAST(UpdateDate AS DATE) = CAST(c1.UpdateDate AS DATE) 
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to do use `group by` and `having` to get a set of account id, date pairs and then filter against that set.

DECLARE @testTable TABLE (AccountID INT, UpdatedDate DATETIME)

```
INSERT INTO @testTable
VALUES ('123', '11/1/2017 08:00:00:000'), 
       ('123', '11/1/2017 20:00:00:000'), 
       ('123', '11/2/2017 08:00:00:000'), 
       ('456', '11/1/2017 08:00:00:000'), 
       ('456', '11/1/2017 14:00:00:000'), 
       ('456', '11/1/2017 20:00:00:000'), 
       ('789', '11/1/2017 08:00:00:000'), 
       ('789', '11/2/2017 08:00:00:000');

WITH grouped AS (SELECT AccountID
        , CAST(UpdatedDate AS DATE)  AS UpdatedDateOnly
    FROM @testTable
    GROUP BY AccountID, CAST(UpdatedDate AS DATE)
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
SELECT tt.*
FROM @testTable tt
INNER JOIN grouped g
    ON g.AccountID = tt.AccountID
    AND g.UpdatedDateOnly <= tt.UpdatedDate 
         AND tt.UpdatedDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, g.UpdatedDateOnly);
```